# ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessor_pb2' in the training part after installation was successful

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I installed the object detection API correctly using this https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md and I checked by running model_builder_test.py
This gave me a OK result.
Then I moved on to running the train.py on my dataset using the following command

python train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=pipeline.config --train_dir=train_file

And I am getting the error ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessor_pb2'
This particular preprocessor_pb2.py exists in the path it is looking for i.e

C:\Users\SP-TestMc\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\models-master\models-master\research\object_detection\protos

What could be the reason for this error then?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#protobuf-compilation. Sounds like you need to compile the protos before using the Python scripts.